# How to remove conflict package in ubuntu?

Tags: apt, python, dependencies

```
punit@punit-Compaq-420:~$ apt-cache depends python2.7-dev
python2.7-dev
  Depends: python2.7
  Depends: libpython2.7-dev
  Depends: libpython2.7
  Depends: libexpat1-dev
 |Recommends: libc6-dev
  Recommends: <libc-dev>
    libc6-dev
  Replaces: python2.7
  Replaces: python2.7:i386
  Conflicts: python2.7-dev:i386
```

How can i remove conflict  python2.7-dev:i386 ??

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you are misinterpreting the information. This does not mean `python2.7-dev:i386` is installed. It means that if you install the 32-bit developer version 2.7 of python it will remove python 2.7 and the 32-bit version of python 2.7.

---

If you want to see what is installed and named "python2.7" you can use

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep python2.7
```

and it should return something like this...

```
libpython2.7:amd64              install
libpython2.7-minimal:amd64          install
libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64           install
python2.7                   install
python2.7-minimal               install
```

---

And to actually answer how to delete it ... Deleting a package is done with 'apt-get remove' or 'apt-get purge' (also removes configuration).

```
sudo apt-get purge python2.7-dev:i386
```

will tell you it is NOT installed ...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python2.7-dev:i386' is not installed, so not removed
```

(please do not do this randomly with packages since it will remove software you might need).